# Translating "a sí mismo, por sí mismo"

Tags: traducción

The phrase is:

> un escritor hecho a sí mismo, por sí mismo

Searching around, both a sí mismo and por sí mismo were translated as "for himself, by himself".

I figure in this context it means:

> a writer made by himself, for himself

Is this correct? What are the proper translations of the above two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "hecho a sí mismo" is best translated as "self-made". And "por sí mismo", as "by himself". So maybe I would translate it as:

> a self-made writer, made by himself

Comment: Self-made does make more sense

Comment: That's a good literal translation, but doesn't really make sense IMO (it sounds redundant, or like the the writer physically created himself). *Self-made writer* alone though sounds like a good translation.

Comment: Yes, I agree it sounds weird. But the original sounds weird too, and is also redundant.